# Why the canvas size in this code is not as expected?

Tags: html, css, canvas

https://jsfiddle.net/awguo/uw1x8m3y/

here is the detailed demo.

I put an img in a div#wrapper and then put a canvas overlap on this img inside that wrapper. I set the width and height of the img and css both to 100%. Then I track the width*height of the canvas. It's not as expected (350x350) but 350x354. Why there is a "4px" more? What should I do to make the canvas size exactly the same as the image (which may also be stretched according to the parent div's width?

Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  // Why it's 350x354, not 350x350?
  var output = 'canvas size: ' + ($('#overlap').css('width') + ' x ' + $('#overlap').css('height'));
  $('#output').val(output);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}
#wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
#overlap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
#output {
  width: 350px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.awflasher.com/300x300_demo.png" />
  <canvas id="overlap"></canvas>
</div>

<h3>
    Output:
    </h3>
<input id="output" type="text" />

<p>
  Why the output is 350x354, not 350x350 as expected?
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the image's display `inline-block` or `block`. By default it is `inline` and gets `vertical-align`ed to `baseline`, so it gets the crazy `0.5em` height extra.

```js
$(function() {
  // Why it's 350x354, not 350x350?
  var output = 'canvas size: ' + ($('#overlap').css('width') + ' x ' + $('#overlap').css('height'));
  $('#output').val(output);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}
#wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#overlap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#output {
  width: 350px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.awflasher.com/300x300_demo.png" />
  <canvas id="overlap"></canvas>
</div>

<h3>
  Output:
</h3>
<input id="output" type="text" />

<p>
  Why the output is 350x354, not 350x350 as expected?
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: OMG, that answer is so fast. Thanks guys, I'll take a try!

Comment: I guess you meant `inline`, `baseline` is not a valid value for `display`

Comment: @Kaiido I meant the `vertical-align` value. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Quite confusing yes. Then no need for the display block, just set `vertical-align:top`on the img will do too.

Comment: @Kaiido True... That's another way.